# ng-controller variable Vs ng-init vairable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller, ng-init

For below code, using angularJS,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('app').controller('add', ['$scope',function($scope) {
           $scope.name = "Bonita Ln";
    }]);
</script>
```

corresponding Javascript code to access `$scope` variable member `name` is,

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="add">
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var dom_el = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="add"]');
       var ng_el = angular.element(dom_el);
       var ng_el_scope = ng_el.scope();
       var name = ng_el_scope.name;
   </script>
</div>
```

Below is the angular code, accessing `ng-init` variable `name` using angular expression,

```
<body ng-app="">
    <div ng-init="name='Bonita Ln'">
        {{name}}
    </div>
</body>
```

How do I access the `ng-init` variable `name` using JavaScript?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oomum13b/1/

Comment: I recommend you to read an angular tutorial, the way you are using angular is not a good practice.

Comment: @Serginho I am not considering as good practice.

Comment: If you had learnt an angular tutorial, you wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: @Cherniv If I do not keep JS code under `document.ready`, then I see error `angular.element().scope() undefined` http://jsfiddle.net/oomum13b/2/

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by accessing variable `$scope.name` in your controller, but it has to be define inside your scope.

```
<div ng-init="name='Bonita Ln'">
  {{name}}
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name2}}!
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.name2 = $scope.name;
})
```

this works, as you have define name in parent scope to controller, and is being inherited

but if for same controller html template will look like that:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<div ng-init="name='Bonita Ln'">
  {{name}}
Hello, {{name2}}!
  </div>
</div>
```

then it won't work, as variable was undefined when controller function was invoked

Answer (score 0):

You could use it in exactly the same way, but you shouldn't.

I've downvoted your question because it is really really really bad practice, and I mean like every line of code you provided is bad practice.

I'm struggling trying to find out what you'd like to do, so I can't really provide you with better code to do so, but I can provide you with some links you must check out before continuing with whatever you're coding now.

- [Shaping up with Angular](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro) is a free codeschool course provided by the angular team, it is a really good course that will give you more insight on how to use angular than the phone-tutorial on the angular website.
- [Papa Johns Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) a great guide on how to write maintainable code.
- [thinkster.io](https://thinkster.io/a-better-way-to-learn-angularjs) a step by step guide to learn to master Angular
- [egghead.io](https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs) a collection of good video tutorials

I know that my comment sounds quite harsh, but future you will thank you if you write more standardized Angular, and keep to a defined style-guide.
Also remember, in angular, your code should not know about the DOM, you don't need to specify eventListeners to DOM-elements, just use the appropriate directives like `ng-click`.
*(yes I am aware that there can be exceptions to the rule)*